# Show positions of duplicated matrix elements

Tags: matrix, function-construction

**1. Problem statement**

I want to replace duplicated elements within a matrix with a placeholder value.

**2. Example data**

```
SeedRandom[0];
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {5, 5}];
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

There are several duplicated values between rows and one value, `68`, repeated within a row (I use `duplicated` and `repeated` as synonyms, meaning `more than once`).

**3. UniqueElements**

Since V 13.1 there is `UniqueElements` which deletes duplicated matrix elements,
but results in a ragged list, not showing the positions of the deleted values.

```
UniqueElements[mat] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**4. The solution found**

```
    PaddedSingles[mat_?MatrixQ, rep_ : 0] :=
     (* intra row replacements *)
     ReplaceRepeated[{h___, a_, m___, a_, t___} :> {h, a, m, rep, t}] /@
      (* between rows replacements *)
      Table[
        mat[[i]] /. Alternatives @@ Union @ Flatten @ Delete[mat, {i}] :> rep,
        {i, Length @ mat}]
```

**5. Expected result**

```
res = PaddedSingles[mat];
res // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Check

```
DeleteCases[res, 0, {2}] == UniqueElements[mat]
```

(* True *)

**6. Further examples**

```
mat = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}};
res = PaddedSingles[mat, x]
```

{{x, x, x}, {x, x, x}, {x, x, 2}}

```
DeleteCases[res, x, {2}] == UniqueElements[mat]
```

(* True *)

```
mat = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
res = PaddedSingles[mat, x]
```

{{x, x}, {x, x}}

```
DeleteCases[res, x, {2}] == UniqueElements[mat]
```

(* True *)

**7. Question**

Maybe I should be happy with this solution, but I always feel a little bad when I have to use `Table` or iterators. Also, because of the mapped `ReplaceRepeated` and iterated `ReplaceAll`, my solution should become very slow when acting on large matrices. Reasons enough to ask for alternative methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
duplicatePositions = 
  Apply[Join] @
  ReplaceAll[p : {{x_, _} ..} :> Rest[p]] @
  Select[Length @ # > 1 &] @
  GatherBy[Tuples @ Range @ Dimensions @ #, 
      $x |-> #[[Apply[Sequence] @ $x]]] &
```

You can use `duplicatePositions` with [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) or with [`ReplaceAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAt.html)
or with [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html):

```
paddedSingles = MapAt[#2, duplicatePositions @ #] @ # &;

MatrixForm[paddedSingles[mat, x &]]
```

[image]

```
paddedSinglesB = ReplaceAt[_ -> #2, duplicatePositions @ #] @ # &;

paddedSinglesC = ReplacePart[#, duplicatePositions[#] -> #2] &;


paddedSingles[mat, x &] == paddedSinglesB[mat, x] ==  paddedSinglesC[mat, x]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

An alternative, slower, method to find the desired position list:

```
duplicatePositions2 = Apply[Join] @
    ReplaceAll[p : {{x_, _} ..} :> Rest[p]] @
    Select[Length[#] >= 2 &] @
    Map[$x |-> Position[#, $x, {2}]] @ 
    Apply[Union] @ # &;

Sort @ duplicatePositions @ mat == Sort @ duplicatePositions2 @ mat
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: (+1) It's always a challenge to find alternatives to your answers, but this is how I achieve some training :-)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using SparseArray:

```
ClearAll[PaddedSingles];
PaddedSingles[mat_?MatrixQ, rep_ : 0] :=
  (f |-> f -> If[Length@f > 1, rep, First@#])[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Last@#, First]] & /@
   Normal@GroupBy[ArrayRules[SparseArray[mat], rep], Last -> First] //
     Normal@SparseArray[Splice@*Thread /@ #] &

testmat = {
  {{84, 67, 5, 22, 72}, {68, 17, 68, 77, 29}, {22, 44, 18, 47, 54}
                      , {85, 86, 18, 51, 16}, {100, 61, 2, 20, 44}}
, {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}
, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}};

PaddedSingles /@ testmat 

(*
{{{84, 67, 5, 0, 72}, {68, 17, 0, 77, 29}, {0, 0, 0, 47, 54}
                    , {85, 86, 0, 51, 16}, {100, 61, 2, 20, 0}}
, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}
, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}

*)
DeleteCases[PaddedSingles@#, 0, {2}] == UniqueElements[#] & /@ testmat
(*{True, True, True}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
UniqueDuplicatePositions[mat_] := 
Catenate@Keys@GroupBy[Select[Position[mat, #] & /@ DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@mat, 
Length[#] > 1 &], If[Equal @@ #[[All, 1]], Rest@#, #] &]
```

Then, using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[#, Thread[UniqueDuplicatePositions[#] -> x]] &@ mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

@eldo always comes up with the kind of questions that make you rethink the very logic you're familiar with. And @kglr? He's the kind of genius who always seems to have the perfect solution tucked away. Keeping up with these two feels like trying to debug a perfectly written Wolfram code: super intriguing, and always a delightful challenge!

Utilizing a segment from @kglr's code, we observe a quicker alternative as follows:

```
UniqueDuplicatePositions[mat_] := Catenate[ReplaceAll[
p : {{x_, _} ..} :> Rest[p]]@(Position[mat, #] & /@ 
Select[Tally[Flatten[mat]], #[[2]] > 1 &][[All, 1]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[keepLocalDuplicates, dpos];
dpos[k_List] := 
 Position[k, #] & /@ (k // DeleteDuplicates) // Map[Rest] // Flatten
keepLocalDuplicates[mat_?MatrixQ, repl_ : "x"] := 
 Module[{mat2, cfull, pos2},
  mat2 = If[DuplicateFreeQ@#, #, 
      ReplacePart[#, Thread[dpos@# -> repl]]] & /@ mat;
  cfull = Map[Count[Flatten@mat2, #] &, mat2, {2}];
  pos2 = Position[cfull, _?(# > 1 &)];
  ReplacePart[mat2, Thread[pos2 -> repl]]
  ]

testCases = {
   {{84, 67, 5, 22, 72}, {68, 17, 68, 77, 29}, {22, 44, 18, 47, 
     54}, {85, 86, 18, 51, 16}, {100, 61, 2, 20, 44}}
   , {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}
   , {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
   };

{ testCases // Map[MatrixForm], 
  keepLocalDuplicates /@ testCases // Map[MatrixForm]} // Column
```

[image]

---

**Addendum**

Here is a function based on `Fold` that marks duplicated elements from a list. This can be used as a building block.

```
Clear[UniqueElements];
UniqueElements[k_List, repl_ : "x"] := 
 Fold[Append[#1, If[FreeQ[#1, #2], #2, repl]] &, {}, k]

SeedRandom[1];
t1 = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 20];

{t1, UniqueElements[t1]} // Grid
```

[image]